# evolution needed for thunderbird?

Tags: gnome, thunderbird, evolution, gsettings

I renamed every running evolution file to disabled suffix:

```
# ls  -l evolution-*disabled
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  10392 Feb 15 01:38 evolution-addressbook-factory.disabled
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  79952 Feb 15 09:44 evolution-alarm-notify.disabled
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  10392 Feb 15 01:38 evolution-calendar-factory.disabled
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  14536 Feb 15 01:38 evolution-calendar-factory-subprocess.disabled
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 101000 Feb 15 01:38 evolution-source-registry.disabled
```

Also I changed my default MUA in `gnome-control-center` and I ran the following command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.office.calendar exec icedove
```

`icedove` is thunderbird uder Debian OS.

**But my question:**

Does `thunderbird` need to running some `evolution` commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No: `thunrerbird` and `evolution` are two separate projects/softwares/...

You may very well purge `evolution` from your system.

Comment: Unfortunately, gnome package depends on `evolution`.

Comment: Sorry to ear that. Using XFCE here: it is not.

Comment: @PersianGulf: I'm not a Debian user, but according to https://wiki.debian.org/Gnome#Options you may try installing the `gnome-core` package instead of `gnome`. The former doesn't depend on `evolution` while the latter does.

Comment: @FrancescoTurco : `gnome-core` depends on `gnome`

Comment: @PersianGulf: As far as I can see it's the opposite: `gnome` depends on `gnome-core`. But I'm not a Debian user, so I may have an incorrect understanding of things...